# Area51 user flair not updating

Tags: bug, area-51, flair

My Area51 user/flair that displays on proposals hasn't updated in at least a week.

Currently it shows

[image: flair]

instead of

[image: what flair should look like]

(and no, the differences aren't due to the omission or inclusion of Cross-Validated).

Comment: Most likely by design, it's taking only top 6.

Comment: If so it's doing it in a very weird way: It's including badge counts from top 8 or 9.

Comment: I think the badge mismatch was already reported, but for the life of me can't find it. Either getting rusty, or I imagine things... :/